# Does 'msgMultiSend' of Cosmos coin, guarantee the order of input and output?

Tags: blockchain, transfer, cosmos, cosmos-sdk

I am a coin wallet developer, and I am investigating Cosmos' transfer this time.

Cosmos has `msgMultiSend` as well as `msgSend`.

I know that MsgMultiSend sends several transfers using `inputs` and `outputs` in the form of an array.

At this time, I wonder if the order of `inputs` and `outputs` is matched one on one and guaranteed.

(i.e., whether the recipient matching the first sender of inputs is always guaranteed to be the first of outputs.)

(i.e.

- transfer 1 : inputs[0] -> outputs[0]
- transfer 2 : inputs[1] -> outputs[1]
  ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In cosmos 0.45.9, cosmjs 0.28.11, `msgMultiSend` have inputs that must be the same address. If you have multiple input addresses, you must have multiple signatures to verify them. And when I try to do this, the SDK show error `BroadcastTxError: Broadcasting transaction failed with code 4 (codespace: sdk). Log: wrong number of signers; expected 1, got 2: unauthorized at CosmWasmClient.broadcastTx`. But if you use the same address, It'll successful. Example on Aura Network Testnet: [A070ED2C0557CFED34F48BF009D2E21235E79E07779A80EF49801F5983035F1B](https://explorer.dev.aura.network/transaction/A070ED2C0557CFED34F48BF009D2E21235E79E07779A80EF49801F5983035F1B). Click JSON to view Raw Data.
- And the sum token amount of inputs should equal the sum token amount of outputs. If it's not equal, this error will throw `Broadcasting transaction failed with code 4 (codespace: bank). Log: sum inputs != sum outputs`.
- You can see the events data of the transaction to know more about this typeUrl.
  Example:
  [1 input send to 19 outputs](https://explorer.dev.aura.network/transaction/274B245DA9DCC25C0EC23DE0FCDC2BF9E1D2E2BC0328F4A6A768AA57F919660D)